# jquery using .text() able to change boostrap class first span but not second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm very new to javascript/html and jquery and read through as many of the questions about changing span elements with the jquery .text() command and none of them seem to make a difference for my specific case, which is using jquery to change the text of 2 span elements in the same div.

Here's what i've got for my HTML

```
<div>
      <p>
         <span class="label label-primary" id="mstatusDim">loading..</span>
         <span class="label label-warning" id="warmup">loading</span>
      </p>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
   $("#mstatusDim").text(result.stat);
   $("warmup").text("test");
```

The function they are in is a getJSON call that returns result.XXX

But for some reason I don't understand i'm never able to change the text of the "warmup" id span.

i've also tried changing the class to be unique as well by doing the following

```
<div>
  <p>
     <span class="mstat label label-primary" id="mstatusDim">loading..</span>
     <span class="warmuptest label label-warning" id="warmup">loading</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

but no luck there either. Even if I switch the order of them the "mstatusDim" span will always update correctly and the "warmup" never will so that's why i'm scratching my head so much since it's partly working...

in an ideal world I want the second span to have no text and not be visible unless I pass it the .text("XYZ") in which case it would appear with the information

```
  <span class="mstat label label-primary" id="mstatusDim">loading..</span>
  <span class="warmuptest label label-warning" id="warmup"></span>
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just missed an ID selector ('#')

change

```
$("warmup").text("test");
```

to

```
$("#warmup").text("test");
```

Comment: Wow i feel like an idiot...apparently i just need to go home and go to sleep... I've been staring at this for way longer than I care to admit. Thanks!